# Are carbonated drinks deadly?

Tags: medical-science, drinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is carbonated water unhealthy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/is-carbonated-water-unhealthy)

Yes, I know they contain sugar and can cause obesity etc. I refer to claims made on the internet about them being acidic enough to dissolve through teeth, about it killing small insects etc. So how much truth is there to such claims?

Comment: Yes, they cause death after an average of 75 years.

Comment: Yes, half gallon of soda in 30 minutes can make one queasy, and more than 1 gallon can kill ya.